# Coloring cells in C++ builder, StringGrid

Tags: c++, c++builder, stringgrid

I tried to do this:

```
void __fastcall TTetrisGame::DrawGrid1DrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
    TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
    this->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
    this->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
}
```

But it is a really weird result. I put my StringGrid in the middle of the window but I can't see any Blue color. Instead, it is transparent. I see a colored blue Grid in the right top corner of my window.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I color each cell individually?

Answer (score 2):

### You are painting on the wrong `Canvas`.

Inside your `OnDrawCell` event handler, `this` refers to the parent Form, because the handler is a member of the `TTetrisGame` class. As such, you are painting on the Form's `Canvas`. You need to paint on the Grid's `Canvas` instead:

```
void __fastcall TTetrisGame::DrawGrid1DrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow, TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
    DrawGrid1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
    DrawGrid1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
}
```